# Does this sentence imply the FET will be turned on if it were not already?

Tags: power, mosfet, switches, diode-clamp

"If the voltage potential from
VBB to VOUT exceeds the clamping voltage, the power FET will allow current to flow from VBB to VOUT (path 3)."

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps1hb50-q1.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1692829680936

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the FET switches off an inductive load, the inductor current will cause the Vout pin to start dropping, increasing the voltage across the FET.  If it reaches the clamp voltage, in order to prevent damage to the FET, it will turn back on to keep the voltage within safe limits.